# Dynamic number of rows in itextsharp

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf, stored-procedures, itext

I would like to generate a pdf using itextsharp with dynamic number of rows according to the number of records I get back from my stored procedure.

For instance, if I have 3 records in my stored procedure I would like the itextsharp to generate it like this:

(column 1)         (column 2)       (column 3)

row 1   Bread                1$                93215321

row 2   Milk                1.5$              12345678

row 3   Sausage             5$                54678912

For the next pdf , if the stored procedure contains 5 records, it would display 3 columns and 5 rows.

Is this possible to do using itextsharp? Someone help me please :)!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I've even written a whole book about it.

You probably want to use the `PdfPTable` class. This class is explained in [chapter 4](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=4). See for instance the [HeaderFooter1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=86) example where I loop over a database containing many movie titles and screenings of these movies. The result is a PDF with tables that have as many rows as there are records that correspond with a certain day: [header_footer_1.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter04/header_footer_1.pdf)

I see that you are using iTextSharp, so you may want to take a look at the [C# port of the examples](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04).

Creating a `PdfPTable` is very easy. You just create an instance of the class and then add `PdfPCell` instances to it. This is an example that also introduces rowspan and colspan:

```
// a table with three columns
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
// the cell object
PdfPCell cell;
// we add a cell with colspan 3
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
table.AddCell(cell);
// now we add a cell with rowspan 2
cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));
cell.Rowspan = 2;
table.AddCell(cell);
// we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
table.AddCell("row 1; cell 1");
table.AddCell("row 1; cell 2");
table.AddCell("row 2; cell 1");
table.AddCell("row 2; cell 2");
```

In your case, it's sufficient to create a `PdfPTable` with 3 columns as done in the short code snippet, and then to create a loop over all the records from the result set of your stored procedure. Put the content of each field in a `PdfPCell` and add that cell to the `PdfPTable`. Once the loop is finished, add the `PdfPTable` to a `Document` instance.

**Warning:** some people might consider your question a "homework" question. Your question doesn't show what you've tried. Usually people expect you to do some effort before posting a question. Don't shoot the messenger. I'm only giving you a heads up so that you're not surprised if your question gets downvoted or closed.